# git fsck -- If this is clean then is git repo in good shape? (I put my repos in dropbox and want to check integrity)

Tags: git, fsck

I accidentally put my repositories in dropbox.

One of my repositories I couldn't do git status without a message about a missing tree. (git fsck also reported this)

On the other ones I did git fsck and there was just dangling objects and commits. If git fsck is clean or just has dangling objects/commits am I safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Dangling commits" and similar for objects indicates that the repository itself is not *broken*.  It's possible that you've lost a commit or two off some branch, but if so, the repository itself is at least consistent.  Check the tip commit of each of your branches<sup>1</sup> to see if the last commit is what you expect.  (Repeat with your remote-tracking names if applicable, although here you can just use `git fetch` to fix things).

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g., for each branch, run `git show name`.  Or, `git log --no-walk --branches` will list out each branch tip commit.

Comment: If you use `git rebase -i` as much as I do, you'll learn that to get usable output in long run you really want to use `git fsck --no-dangling` instead. Basically all the old commits left behind after rebasing your branches multiple times are technically dangling commits. You can consider those as parts of the repository that *could* be released to reduce disk usage. I prefer to keep those around for longer than the default 90 days so my `git fsck` keeps listing those by default.